# 404 when accessing site remotely

Tags: 2010

I am trying to access a site located at 10.0.45.62 (intranet ip). 
When I am on that server I can reach the site via 
http://w-10-0-45-62:16191/test/SitePages/Home.aspx

When I attempt to connect remotely via browser, using the IP of the machine, 
http://10.0.45.62:16191/test/SitePages/Home.aspx I get a 404 err. What can I do to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure an Alternate Access Mapping in CA, under your Web application. (CA-> Manage Web applications -> Alternate Access Mapping). Add an new entry, with the IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

Go into central administration - Application Management - Configure Alternate Access Mappings, select the appropriate web application and add http://10.0.45.62:16191 as one of the Public Urls for the web app.  That will tell SharePoint to respond to those requests.

You may need to add that to the web application directly in IIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. Its such a newbie thing I dont even want to mention it.... I created the subsite as part of SharepointCentral - not as a site on its own under Sharepoint-80. Thats the reason for all the issues. Thanks to Dave and 1c1cle for trying to help!